# win32api.messagebox gets called on program start

Tags: python

I have a very simple Python program that I am using to get familiar with the win32api message calls.  I put a line in my program

```
mywin['button'].onclick = win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
```

The problem is that the message box gets displayed as soon as the program starts.  And it does not get displayed when the button is clicked.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is the rest of my code:

```
import gui
import win32api

gui.Window(name='mywin', title=u'gui2py minimal app', resizable=True, height='459px', width='400px', image='', )
gui.Button(label=u'Click me!', name='button', left='8', top='115', default=True, parent='mywin', )

# get a reference to the Top Level Window:
mywin = gui.get("mywin")

mywin['button'].onclick = win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')

if name == "main":
    mywin.show()
    gui.main_loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the `.onclick` attribute to the *return value* of calling `win32api.MessageBox`.  It is no different than doing:

```
value = win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
mywin['button'].onclick = value
```

To fix the problem, you can use a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-lambda_expr):

```
mywin['button'].onclick = lambda: win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
```

The above assigns the `.onclick` attribute to the lambda function.  When the button is clicked, the lambda will be called and the `win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')` code will be executed.

Comment: OK, I entered: mywin['button'].onclick = lambda: win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title') but the message box still gets displayed as soon as I press "Run" and it does not get displayed when I click the button.  Do I need to import anything for lambda?

Comment: I also tried adding your lines:

value = win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
mywin['button'].onclick = value

But got the same thing.  Shows the message when Run and not when clicked.

Comment: No, you do not need to import anything because `lambda` is a keyword.  Are you maybe calling `win32api.MessageBox` in another place?  That, or you could be handling the click events incorrectly.  Could you please post the rest of your code?  There is not enough to work with at this point.

Comment: I just saw this in the "Interactive Window":

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\psf\Home\Downloads\gui2py-0.9.3\gui\spec.py", line 79, in handler
    action(event)   # just call the user function
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Yes, the code is very small.  I posted it on my DropBox here:  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtxqkan1p6swrwo/minimal.pyw?dl=0)

Comment: If the code is very small, then please post it here in your question.  Links can become invalidated over time.  As for your `TypeError`, I would assume you are not using the return value of `win32api.MessageBox` correctly.  The function returns an integer error code to signal the state in which it exited.

Comment: I tried!  But it says "your code is too long by 63 characters"

Comment: I will try in 2 pieces:

    import gui     
    import win32api 
    gui.Window(name='mywin', title=u'gui2py minimal app', resizable=True, 
           height='459px', width='400px', image='', )
    gui.Button(label=u'Click me!', name='button', left='8', top='115', 
           default=True, parent='mywin', )
    # get a reference to the Top Level Window:

    mywin = gui.get("mywin")

Comment: here is the rest:
    value = win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
    mywin['button'].onclick = value
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    mywin.show()    
    gui.main_loop()

Comment: I meant post it in the *question*, not the comments.  But that's OK, I'll do it for you.  Unfortunately though, I don't have the `gui` module installed where I am (or any experience with it), so I can't run your code.  Your problem though is most likely being caused by something similar to what I said in my answer (you are calling `win32api.MessageBox` before you should).